# How to bind layout_margintop in xamarin android using mvvmcross + c#

Tags: xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I want to bind the layout_marginTop with model value.
I am able to bind Text and also command but unable to bind layout_marginTop.
For example,

> mvvm:MvxBind="Text Title;layout_marginTop TopMargin"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do so you need [Custom data binding](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/custom-data-binding) because Mvx does not have margin top binding by default.

Create the target binding class:

```
public class MarginTopTargetBinding : MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding
{
    public MarginTopTargetBinding(object target, PropertyInfo targetPropertyInfo) 
        : base(target, targetPropertyInfo)
    {
    }

    protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
    {
        var view = target as View;
        if (view == null)
            return;

        var marginParams = view.LayoutParameters as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams;
        if (marginParams == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("You can't set a margin to a View which Layoutparameters are not derived from MarginLayoutParams");

        marginParams.TopMargin = (int)value;

        view.LayoutParameters = marginParams;

        view.RequestLayout();
    }
}
```

And then you just register it in your `Setup.cs`:

```
protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
{
    base.FillTargetFactories(registry);

    registry.RegisterPropertyInfoBindingFactory(
        typeof(MarginTopTargetBinding),
        typeof(View), "MarginTop");
}
```

And use it like:

`mvvm:MvxBind="Text Title; MarginTop TopMargin"`

BTW you could have a more complex object `MyCustomMarginModel` that have all four properties of margin and do a custom binding for that so you could bind every margin whenever you want.

HIH